# LINQ + join with nested foreach razor output writing out title lines from groupby

Tags: c#, linq, join, foreach, razor

I have a basic store model. I have Items, Items have a category, and categories have a menu. I want to list the items of a given menu grouped by the item categories so that it writes the category name then lists the items under it and moves on to the next category. I'm getting beat up by the syntax. Please help.

Items:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Categories:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

Menus:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I have the linq statement:

```
    var model = from i in _db.Items
                join c in _db.Categories on i.Category.ID equals c.ID
                join m in _db.Menus on c.Menu.ID equals m.ID
                where m.Name == menuName
                select i;
```

I'm pretty sure that won't work with the select i but I'm out of ideas and that is it's curent state.

In the view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.Item>
```

And I have tried everything I can think of to get the grouping to work and nothing has. I even tried just setting a variable to the currentCategoryID and checking if it changed then writing the category name but it errors out when it hits @item.Category.Name saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm totally lost. :(

**UPDATE**
OK, We got that part working, now is there a way to make this loop more elegant? I don't like the temp var to check if it's a new category.

```
int currentCategory = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        if (!item.Category.ID.Equals(currentCategory))
        {
            <h3>@item.Category.Name</h3>
           currentCategory = item.Category.ID;
        }

        <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

            </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your query looks good and should produce the expected results - provided you do not have null properties for `Menu` or `Category`.

Could it be that some of your categories contain null as a `Menu` property? In that case your join will throw a NullReferenceException since you directly try to access `c.Menu.ID` - a workaround would be this:

```
var model = from i in Items
            join c in Categories on i.Category.ID equals c.ID
            where c.Menu !=null
            join m in Menus on c.Menu.ID equals m.ID
            where m.Name == menuName
            select i;
```

Same problem with the `Category` property of `Item` - if it can be `null` you have to exclude those items since you use the `category.ID` property:

```
var model = from i in Items
            where i.Category != null
            join c in Categories on i.Category.ID equals c.ID
            where c.Menu !=null
            join m in Menus on c.Menu.ID equals m.ID
            where m.Name == menuName
            select i;
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

Since no properties are null we can drop that part from the query again - but you also need to specify which related entities you want to materialize when you retrieve entities from the context. In your case you need the related `Category` property as well, which you can specify using `Include()`:

```
var model = from i in Items.Include("Category")
            join c in Categories on i.Category.ID equals c.ID
            where c.Menu !=null
            join m in Menus on c.Menu.ID equals m.ID
            where m.Name == menuName
            select i;
```

Comment: No. None are null, I tried adding your suggestion and still no go. For some reason even though intelisense autocompletes @items.Category.Name on the view page, it throws a fit when I try to run it. @item.Name, item.price etc work just fine.

Comment: @Twisted: Ah now we are getting to the heart of this: Is this Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL? You need to specify what related entities you want to materialize.

Comment: it's against a db. I'm kinda new to this whole thing so I'm a bit lost in terminology. I have a DB model as well and I let the entity framework build the db after I made the classes. I will add I pulled out all the joins because I don't know they need to be there to accomplish what I want (my brain is fried, I've been at this all day) and it still gives the same results. I can access @item.Name, but not @item.category.name even though intelisense sees it.

Comment: First off, you're my hero. My brain can relax. I do have a second part to the question though. I added it in the update. I don't like the grouping method I devised, but it works. Is there a more elegant way to do that?